# How to connect remotely to a SQL Server 2012 database that resides on a Godaddy Windows VPS, I am using ssms for connecting remotely

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, vps

I am using SSMS to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database that resides on my Godaddy VPS. I'm unable to connect from SSMS, but I can connect normally from inside the domain.

I have opened port 1433 for TCP connections through RDP (IPAll). I have restarted SQL Server also. But am not sure whether my Windows Server machine allows inbound connection to 1433.

On SSMS login I am using

- server name as `ip-address:1433`
- authentication as SQL Server authentication
- followed by username, password

But I'm unable to connect.

Comment: Opening port 1433 on your server to the outside world is normally a bad idea, unless you're locking down the port to specific IPs. If not, your Server is going to be wide open to brute force attacks. This isn't anything to do with SQL Server though, and to do with the administration of the server so you would likely be better off asking on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: oh thanks, I would certainly limit down the port 1433 to my workplace static ip. thanks a lot for your advise.